# Кто слушает порт

Tags: сеть, tcp

У меня возникает конфликт между почтовым сервером и ещё каким-то одним сервисом.

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':25'
```

Вывод:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, кто слушает 25 порт. Как это можно определить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустите из под sudo или суперпользователя и увидите pid процесса:

> sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':25'

Comment: Спасибо, ща разберусь, думаю.

Comment: это какой-то процесс postfix

Comment: @hedgehogues не «какой-то», а postfix это и есть почтовый сервер

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть с помощью iproute2: `ss -tulpn | grep ':25'`

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогло. Нет ни одного процесса